# Using symbols to set options

Tags: functions, symbols

I would like to use a symbol to set an option.  I am currently using a variable `cune-launch` to determine when to execute `cune-tools`.

```
(defvar cune-launch t)
(defun cune ()
  "Loads cune and launches tools if desired."

  (add-to-list 'load-path "~/bin/cune")
  (require 'cune)

  (when cune-launch (cune-tools)) )
```

Having seen for instance `modus-themes` using `(setq modus-themes-fringes 'intense)` for setting options, I would like to have something similar.

The option would then decide when to call `(cune-tools)`.

Comment: Dunno what you're asking, sorry. Maybe someone else does.

Comment: I am interested in how you make and pass symbols.
Can the option be executed with a symbol. Would something like `(cune 'launch)` make sense, or is there some specific way?

Comment: Your description isn’t very clear, perhaps because it’s not using familiar words and phrases. What does it mean to make or pass a symbol? What does it mean to execute an option? What do you want `(cune 'launch)` to do, and how does it relate to the rest of the code that you put in your question? Have you read the [Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html) yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see. In that case, all you need to do is replace `t` with `'launch`, and check to see if the variable `eq`uals `'launch`.

```lisp
(defvar cune-launch 'launch)
(defun cune ()
  "Loads cune and launches tools if desired."

  (add-to-list 'load-path "~/bin/cune")
  (require 'cune)

  (when (eq cune-launch 'launch)
    (cune-tools)))
```

If `cune-launch` is anything else (such as `nil` or `'no` or `'yes-please`), then `cune-tools` will not be called. However, because there are only two possibilities there really isn’t much point in using symbols here; a boolean will do just as well. Symbols are occasionally used when there are three or more options for something.

Comment: Divine.  Although there might not be much point in this one, I wanted to see how I can better myself and start using symbols comfortably.